# USB Device works on one computer and not another

Tags: windows, usb

I have an ip camera with a motor mounted to it that is used to zoom the lens. This motor is controlled by software that came with the motor. A USB cable is used to link the computer to the motor.

When I plug this device (the USB cable) into my laptop it works perfectly. When plugging into the desktop where it needs to be used, it does not work. By not working I mean the software that controls the motor report that it could not connect to any motor. Both computers use Windows XP 32 bit.

Looking in my device manager in my laptop (where the motor works) I see that it shows 'USB Device' under 'Other Devices'. Under the device manager for the desktop, however, it shows 'Other Devices' and in that it has ' USB Device' - where company name is the name of the company who sold me the motor.

When I plug this USB cable into my laptop a bubble pops up near my system clock saying that a new USB device was inserted, and then it leaves me alone. The Desktop pops this up and then tries to walk me through the new hardware wizard.

Could it be possible that the new hardware wizard on the desktop (which fails because I close it out because the motor came with it's own software driver) could be causing my desktop to somehow ignore that usb port while the motor is plugged in?

Any help would really be appreciated I need to get this motor working on my desktop. Thanks!

Comment: Is the Desktop XP having service-pack 2 (right-click on my-computer and go to properties to check)? If yes, then do a clean uninstall, then reinstall your motor software again.

Answer (score 1):

The new hardware wizard is popping up because there is no installed driver found for the device.  Either the install was skipped or the driver is misconfigured.  Try re-installing the  manufacturer's software or try pointing the new hardware wizard at the install disk.